# using jstl logical tags

Tags: jstl

Inside `<c:chosse>` when we have multiple `<c:when>` tags, it behaves as if, else if, else if...logical constructs. But if I want to do:

```
if(){
  if(){}
  else if{}
  if(){}
  if(){}
  if(){}
  else{} 
}
```

Then can i use `<c:if>` along side `<c:when>` inside `<c:choose>`

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when>
  <c:when>
  <c:if>
  </:if>

  <c:if>
  </:if>

  <c:when>
  </:when>

  <c:when>
  </:when>
  <c:otherwise>
  </:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I seems to work but is the behavior guranteed?

Comment: Without proper indentation, this code is impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jstl but consider to change a logic and move it to backend because it will be too complicated logic in jsp.